# Populate JavaScript array with results from apex methods

Tags: apex, javascript

If I have two simple apex methods in my controller:

```
 public String getStringOne() {
    String returnStringOne = 'this is the string';
    return returnStringOne;
}

 public String getStringTwo() {
    String returnStringTwo = 'this is the other string';
    return returnStringTwo;
}
```

And I have an array in my js file:

```
var myArray = [];
```

How do I pass the results of both of these methods into my array?

```
['this is the string', 'this is the other string']
```

Comment: `myArray.push({!getStringOne});` etc?

Comment: You might also be interested in Javascript Remoting. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Poet's answer handles most of the cases except where the `StringOne` contains Single quotes in it.

If there is a single quote like `StringOne='Lewi\'s'` it will break your Javascript execution, because it will render to

```
     var myArray = ['Lewi's']
```

**Better approach is:**

```
 var myArray = ['{!JSENCODE(StringOne)}', '{!JSENCODE(StringTwo)}'];
```

**Suggestion:**

If the object you want to render becomes bigger and complicated, I would recommend Serializing and Deserializing it as below:

```
    public string getMyArrayContent() {
         List<String> myArray = new List<String>();
         myArray.add('StringOne');
         .
         .
         myArray.Add('StringN');
         return JSON.serialize(myArray);
    }
```

In Javascript:

```
   var myArray = JSON.parse('{!JSENCODE(myArrayContent)}');
```

> - The `JSENCODE` function encodes text strings and merge field values for use in JavaScript by inserting escape characters, such as a backslash `(\)`, before unsafe JavaScript characters, such as the apostrophe `(')`.
> - `{!JSENCODE(text)}` and replace text with the merge field or text string that contains the unsafe JavaScript characters. So it not just prevents you from broken JS but also prevents XSS vulnerability if the string contains unsafe JavaScript code.
> - `JSON.parse(str)` is a Javascript method which takes a String and converts it into Javascript object (Array here)

Comment: Good point! I always forget about those little buggers!

Comment: An explanation of why the JSENCODE/parse can make sense would be helpful here.

Comment: Poet thank you, I have faced this issue on Production org, so I became cautious now :) Daft glad that it helped you @KeithC Updated the explanation,  please let me know if that would help people

Comment: I was really looking for why what you have is better than `var myArray = {!myArrayContent};`...

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to simply do the following:

```
var myArray = ['{!StringOne}', '{!StringTwo}'];
```

Or

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push({!StringOne});
myArray.push({!StringTwo});
```

Effectively because your two methods are just returning a String, you can just render them into the JS on your page and it'll work the same.